# Php Binary Tree Pairs

Tags: php, mysql

I need to find out number of left nodes, number of right nodes and number of pairs(Left + right) from any node of a binary tree.

Each node details is stored in database with its position(Left or right) and Parent node name or code.

How can I do this in ASP.

Comment: Have you already tried something?

Comment: Hello rahulsingh. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. You are expected to try to write the code yourself. After doing more research if you have a problem you can post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working. Once you've attempted to solve the problem, we would be glad to help.

Comment: @C0dekid i had tride many code but not  geting totel left or right pair under user